# How in Qt5 to transfer the form class from the UI to another folder

Tags: qt, qt5, qt-creator

When transferring three files (h, cpp, ui) to another directory, an error occurs.

```
:-1: error: dependent 'enterserialnumber.ui' does not exist.
```

[Default project](https://cloud.mail.ru/public/4dTU/3nXxWSB7Y).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to change your PRO-file and delete those unneeded files.(the #DELETE marks the ones to remove because they simply don't exist anymore in that location.

```
SOURCES += \
     form.cpp \#DELETE
       form/form.cpp \
     main.cpp \
      mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS += \
        form.h \ #DELETE
        form/form.h \
        mainwindow.h

FORMS += \
     form.ui \#DELETE
       form/form.ui \
     mainwindow.ui
```

Then run qmake and rebuild. You should be good to go.

Happy coding!